# Rectangle Scatter Plot with axis type datetime in Bokeh

Tags: python, datetime, plot, axes, bokeh

## Rectangle Scatter Plot with axis type datetime in Bokeh

I would like to create a plot with the x-axis type `datetime`. As an example I used the function `scatter` with squares and the visual variable size.

```
import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import *

figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
scatter([d1,d2,d3], [1,5,3], size=[10,20,30], marker="square")
show()
```

As a second visualization I would replace the square with a rectangle and use the visual variables width and height. Because of the unit division I can not see the width. Is there a solution for this problem (except multiply the width with a factor)? Can I create a new marker?

```
figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
rect([d1,d2,d3], [1,5,3], [1,2,3], [5,1,2])
show()
```

NOTE: I'm using `Python v.2.7.8` and `Bokeh v.0.7.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set `width_units="screen"` in the call to `rect` and then set the width in pixels. Also please note that form of API usage has been deprecated, please consider:

```
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p.rect([d1,d2,d3], [1,5,3], [1,2,3], [5,1,2])
show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the current notation.